# OpenFileDialog shown in a WPF Tab

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Is there any way can we show/attach winforms **OpenFileDialog** in a **WPF** tab?

I have seen few answers with a button in **WPF** tab and when we click on the button a new extra **OpenFileDialog** window is opened but I don't want that extra window, instead I want to show the **OpenFileDialog** in the tab itself kind of attached to the tab.

I need this kind of design because we have a server explorer and we are planning to use a tabbed design with one tab as server explorer and other tab as **OpenFileDialog**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's another window, which is not even `FrameworkElement` or something you could place on your WPF UI, so i think you cannot attach it anywhere inside your window. So I'd say that's impossible. You need to create your own dialog.

Comment: As @MichałTurczyn suggested above, I would create my own **tre view form/component** that I can use to select files and so on, or wouold search for some already created nuget package like Javi.ExplorerTreeView for example (https://github.com/jacovis/Javi.ExplorerTreeView)

Comment: You can use a WindosFormsHost Control. Set its `Child` property to a Panel Control, start the OpenFileDialog in a secondary Thread (e.g., `var t = new Thread(()=> { var ofd = new OpenFileDialog(); ofd.ShowDialog();
}); t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); )`. Use `FindWindowEx()` to find the dialog (after it's handle has been created - requires a small delay - the Class is `#32770`, Caption = `Open`, or whatever that is in the Local Culture), then use `SetParent()` to change the Parent of the Dialog to the `Panel.Handle`. -- This is bad idea, just for *testing*.